# How do you raise CellVariables or ImplicitSourceTerms to a power in FiPy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pde, fipy

With FiPy (Python library) I want to solve the coupled of pdes system shown below. The code below works, but doesn't give the correct solution.

```
p, q, r, s = 2, 1, 2, 0
Du, Dv = 0.0004, 0.04
mesh = Grid1D(nx=500, Lx=5.)

U = CellVariable(name = 'U',mesh=mesh, hasOld=True, value=1.)
V = CellVariable(name = 'V',mesh=mesh, hasOld=True, value=2.)

eqU = TransientTerm(var=U) == DiffusionTerm(coeff=Du, var=U) - U + (U**p)/(V**q)
eqV = TransientTerm(var=V) == DiffusionTerm(coeff=Dv, var=V) - V + (U**r)/(V**s)

viewerV = Viewer(vars=V)
viewerU = Viewer(vars=U)

timeStepDuration = 0.1
steps = 1000

eqn = eqU & eqV

for t in range(500): 
    U.updateOld()
    V.updateOld()
    eqn.solve(dt=1.e-3)
viewerV.plot()
viewerU.plot()
```

In line with some code I saw I also tried to replace the CellVariables with ImplicitSourceTerm, but this gives an error, since taking a ImplicitSourceTerm to the power p can't be done in this way.
However I can't find any documentation on how it should be done:

```
eqU = TransientTerm(var=U) == DiffusionTerm(coeff=Du, var=U) - ImplicitSourceTerm(var=U) + ((ImplicitSourceTerm(var=U)**p)/(ImplicitSourceTerm(var=V)**q))
eqV = TransientTerm(var=V) == DiffusionTerm(coeff=Dv, var=V) - ImplicitSourceTerm(var=V) + ((ImplicitSourceTerm(var=U)**r)/(ImplicitSourceTerm(var=V)**s))
```

Trying to raise U.value**p also gives errors.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing intrinsically wrong with your first solution, other than that the explicit sources may not converge as rapidly as implicit sources would.

An `ImplicitSourceTerm` represents some coefficient times the variable that's being solved for (the default coefficient is 0, [which is useless](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/issues/512), so you must explicitly state `coeff=1.`).

Your terms could be expressed as

```
eqU = TransientTerm(var=U) == DiffusionTerm(coeff=Du, var=U) - ImplicitSourceTerm(var=U, coeff=1.) + ImplicitSourceTerm(var=U, coeff=(U**(p-1))/V**q)
eqV = TransientTerm(var=V) == DiffusionTerm(coeff=Dv, var=V) - ImplicitSourceTerm(var=V, coeff=1.) + ImplicitSourceTerm(var=U, coeff=(U**(r-1))/V**s)
```

You should then use sweeps.

Comment: Thanks for the responds!

I still have trouble getting the right results.
When I set the coeff to U**(p-1), I get the error:
TermMultiplyError: Must multiply terms by int or float.

Using:
f = (U**(r-1))/(V**s)-1.
g = (U**(p-1))/(V**q)

Runs, but doesn't give correct results.

I have been playing around with various ways to implement this term but all failed.
The system either gives U=V=1 as a solution for the whole grid or it goes to infinity for the whole grid.
Where it should show a 'spatial' sinusoid over the grid.

Comment: Also changing U to ImplicitSourceTerm(var=U, coeff=1.) gives completely different solutions.

Comment: Sorry about that. The denominator `V**q` or `V**s` should be part of `coeff`, rather than dividing the `ImplicitSourceTerm`, which isn't allowed.

Comment: I am not surprised that changing `U` to `ImplicitSourceTerm(var=U, coeff=1.)` changes the results. Are you sweeping?